# MySQL: Tagging 1 to each unique occurence during SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample table tbl_name:

```
| ID | Name | Month | Quarter | Year |
| 1  | A    | Jan   |  1      | 2019 |
| 1  | A    | Feb   |  1      | 2019 |
| 2  | B    | May   |  2      | 2019 |
| 3  | C    | May   |  2      | 2018 |
```

Hi, this is the table I extract using SELECT query. I can find the distinct name per year using `SELECT distinct name, year FROM tbl_name;` But I'm trying to add a column during SELECT query to identify or count the unique occurrence per year of the name.

Expected:

```
| ID | Name | Month | Quarter | Year | Unique Count |
| 1  | A    | Jan   |  1      | 2019 |      1       |
| 1  | A    | Feb   |  1      | 2019 |      0       |
| 2  | B    | May   |  2      | 2019 |      1       |
| 3  | C    | May   |  2      | 2018 |      1       |
```

I tried splitting into two queries - one select everything; the other select just distinct and join them together but that will introduce duplicates. Is there a way to do this using SQL?

Comment: Why does February have a _smaller_ count than January?

Comment: Why are you storing the month as a string and not including a column that correctly specifies the ordering?

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is the source data, not like I can do anything about it. I could only use it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` to flag the appearance of a `name` in a `year`:

```
select
    t.*,
    (row_number() over(
        partition by name, year 
        order by str_to_date(concat(year, '-', month), '%Y-%b')
    ) = 1) unique_count
from mytable t
```

Note: do consider fixing the storage strategy of your date columns. Rather than splitting the information over several columns, you would better have a unique column in the relevant `DATE` datatype to store that information. That would save you the pain of recomposing the date when you need it.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ba056ef8c5b14dcf91e63363ef48c98)**:

```
ID | Name | Month | Quarter | Year | unique_count
-: | :--- | :---- | ------: | ---: | -----------:
 1 | A    | Feb   |       1 | 2019 |            1
 1 | A    | Jan   |       1 | 2019 |            0
 2 | B    | May   |       2 | 2019 |            1
 3 | C    | May   |       2 | 2018 |            1
```

Comment: Thanks for that +1, I deleted my comments.  Life would be so much easier for the OP if dates were stored in a single column :-)

Comment: Too bad I have no control over the table schema. Is there a way to do this without partitioning? Seems like the software I'm using doesn't support partition query

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cb7eb403c85b69752d05122c76fa5fc)

```
WITH your_table(ID,Name,Month,Quarter,Year)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'A','Jan',1,2019 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'A','Feb',1,2019 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'B','May',2,2019 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'C','May',2,2018
)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Quarter,Year) RN
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT ID,Name,Month,Quarter,Year,
CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Unique_Count
FROM CTE
```

Output is-

```
ID  Name    Month   Quarter Year    Unique_Count
1   A       Jan     1       2019    1
1   A       Feb     1       2019    0
2   B       May     2       2019    1
3   C       May     2       2018    1
```